# Variables in batch and registry edit for right-click support

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd

I have this batch file which needs to do some stuff in a folder.

This is what i want:

-A shortcut when you right-click. (shell32 i think you should edit with the registry or so...? Can somebody say so?)

-If that shortcut is pressed, the batch is opened, and it locates the folder were was right-clicked. It should set this as a variable, %folder%.

Thanks.

Comment: You do realize that the batch doesn't really help you? All it will do is set the environment variable for the spawning cmd process. Which will die once the batch completes. You can set it in the registry via `setx` but then you always have a `folder` variable, pointing somewhere but every once in a while somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\TEXT_TO_SHOW_IN_EXPLORER_CONTEXT]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\TEXT_TO_SHOW_IN_EXPLORER_CONTEXT\command]
@="C:\\Path\\to\\batch.cmd \"%1\""
```

For the batch file:

```
set folder=%1
:: remove the " from the variable
set folder=%folder:"=%
echo %folder%
```

Comment out line 3 of the batch file if you want to keep `"`'s around the folder path.

Comment: do i always need two slashes for the path to the cmd?

Comment: it seemed to have failed. What i did: -Create new folder -create new command folder -Put the Default string to @="C:\\Path\\to\\batch.cmd \"%1\""

Comment: so, it does not display the option in the right-click shell menu.

Comment: you don't put the default string to the full thing.  You set it to everything after the `=` sign.  So just `"C:\\Path\\to\\batch.cmd \"%1\""`

Comment: also, that only seems to work when you're click on a child folder in Explorer, not the folder that you're currently in.

Comment: uhmmm, it does not work still. i exactly copied the reg stuff to a reg file, did some changes for my prefs, and then just double-clicked to get it. Logged off, logged on... Nothing. Tried in a lot of folders.